# Simple RTMP Python client

Tags: python, flash, client, rtmp

I'm looking for a proper RTMP python client or Python code example that could do at least the following:

1. Properly handshake with Flash server
2. Send a properly encoded (AMF0 or AMF3) "connect" message to the server (and process the result)
3. Send a properly encoded "subscribe" message (and process the result)

I've been investigating [RTMPy](http://www.rtmpy.org/index.html), [rtmplite](http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/), [fmspy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/fmspy/0.1.0) libraries, but haven't gotten anything to work yet. The AMF0 encoding capabilities from rtmplite seem good, though.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [rtmplite](http://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/) could help you?

Answer (score 1):

A minor update on this ...
I've found a lib that might solve the problem: [rtmp-python](https://github.com/prekageo/rtmp-python). rtmplite has been used as a Flash server for testing purposes...

```
from rtmp_python.rtmp_protocol import RtmpClient
cl = RtmpClient(ip="127.0.0.1", port=1935, tc_url='rtmp://localhost/myapp', page_url='', swf_url='', app='myapp')
cl.connect([])
cl.call(proc_name='createStream')
cl.call(proc_name='play', parameters=['user1'])
cl.handle_messages()
```

From the logs I saw that connection had established successfully, "createStream" call worked as well, but "play" didn't... TBC

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import librtmp
conn=librtmp.RTMP(url)
conn.connect(None)
conn_stream=conn.create_stream(0,True)
```

for more information you can visit https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-librtmp/0.2.0